# How Can I Add a Title to this Bar Graph in Python-Jupyter Notebooks?

Tags: python, graph, jupyter-notebook, title

```
hotel_dataframe=hotel_dataframe.groupby(['hotel','meal']).size()
hotel_dataframe=hotel_dataframe.unstack()
meal_comparison=hotel_dataframe.plot(kind='bar')`
```

[image]

How Can I Add a Title to this Bar Graph in Python-Jupyter Notebooks?

Answer (score 0):

You're using pandas' [df.plot()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) method, which takes an optional `title` argument that you can set to any string value:

```py
meal_comparison=hotel_dataframe.plot(kind='bar', 
                                     title='Hotel Comparisons')
```